# Memory leaks with Runnables

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have a question about memory leaks. For example a user opens a screen (let's say a `Fragment`) and clicks a button which starts a new `Runnable` with some operations like getting some data from a web api and then user clicks the back button. Obviously `Runnable` is an anonymous class which implicit keeps a reference to the outer class and while it is running the app is leaking memory. After a few seconds the operation has finished and it stores some data to  the database. So now it's able to be garbage collected plus it has done the job we wanted.

So what I wanna ask is : yes it's a leak but if we don't call a View after the network call it seems to me that it's safe and it helps getting things done.

Should I avoid this way and set Runnable to null when the Fragment/Activity get's destroyed and find another way doing this kind of stuff like i.e. using an `IntentService`?

Comment: use [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html)

Comment: I've created some sigletons to perform network and DB operations in my application. Fragment starts runable inside singleton. After runnable finihed his background operations method onResult() applies processed data in UI thread.